# Lua: no stack trace when calling error() without arguments?

Tags: error-handling, lua

In Lua, calling the standard `error()` function with a message argument outputs the provided error message and also prints stack trace, e.g. executing the following code:

```
print("hello")
error("oops!")
print("world")
```

would result in the following output:

```
$ lua test.lua
hello
lua: test.lua:2: oops!
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    test.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

However, calling `error()` without arguments seems to make Lua die silently without printing stack trace. Executing this code:

```
print("hello")
error()    // no arguments provided
print("world")
```

would result in this output:

```
$ lua test2.lua
hello
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about omitting the first `message` argument:

> error (message [, level])
>
> Terminates the last protected function called and returns message as
>   the error message. Function error never returns. Usually, error adds
>   some information about the error position at the beginning of the
>   message. The level argument specifies how to get the error position.
>   With level 1 (the default), the error position is where the error
>   function was called. Level 2 points the error to where the function
>   that called error was called; and so on. Passing a level 0 avoids the
>   addition of error position information to the message.

I'm wondering if this is intended behavior or no? IMO it would make sense to still print stack trace (and maybe output some default text e.g. `error`) even if no message is provided, because that's how the `assert()` function works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The documentation doesn't say anything about omitting the first message argument:

Yes, it does, `error()` has a prototype like this:

```
error (message [, level])
```

Notice that only the arguments inside `[]` is optional, in this case `level`, otherwise the arguments are mandatory, in this case, `message`.

Comparing with the prototype of `assert()`:

```
assert (v [, message])
```

As you can see, `message` in `assert()` is optional.

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich It doesn't really work because `error` expects a `message` argument. Otherwise it probably depends on the implementation of the function and might cause other errors. If you really want to just pass an empty string `error("")`

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich Because Lua is OK with incompatible numbers of arguments, in that case, `error` will receive the first parameter as `nil`.

Comment: So the error() function probably fails with an internal error and doesn't finish properly... that makes sense, thanks!